# Trying to sort an array alphabetically, but the first item isn't getting sorted

Tags: vb.net

My.Resources.MyList is a text file that contains a list of items, each item on a separate line. For example...

```
Green
Red
Black
Orange
etc.
```

I am trying to sort that list into an array, and then output the results alphabetically into a listbox.

Here's my code...

```
Dim MyListArray() As String = My.Resources.MyList.Split(Environment.NewLine)
Array.Sort(MyListArray)
MyListBox.DataSource = MyListArray
```

But when I do this, the very first item in the list doesn't get sorted (it winds up at the end of the list for some reason). In other words, the end result should look like...

```
Black
Green
Orange
Red
```

But instead it looks like...

```
Black 
Orange
Red
Green
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that there are no hidden chars that cause this issue? Copy paste all into notepad and back into your resources.

Comment: Just tried that, same result.

Comment: Is it possible that the ListBox's selected item gets removed and added back to the end of the array, somewhere in the form... for example, in code which handles one of the ListBox's events?

Comment: I can't get this to work with an array for some reason, so think I'll try to do something similar using a generic list instead. Thanks anyways guys!

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your words don't start/end with an empty character.

```
MyListArray = MyListArray.Select(Function(a) a.Trim()).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorting attribute of listbox is false by default. So try this out:

`Listbox.Sorted = True`

`Listbox.TabIndex = 1`

Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sort.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: You may feed the unsorted array itself and sort it alphabetically in the listbox. However the issue could very well be what Tim and Magnus mentioned too..

Comment: Just tried that too... still no luck. I really don't know why that wouldn't have worked. Strange!

Comment: Can you output your sorted array to see what could be the data inside and if it is really arranged the way you expect it to be... Try changing to a different set of text too. Rather odd if it still persists...